# MySQL if function not work with json_search

Tags: mysql, json

I can't understand.
I expected '["321", "111"]' but I get 'nope'
What is happening?

```
select if(
    JSON_SEARCH('["123", "321", "111"]', 'one', "123"),
    JSON_REMOVE('["123", "321", "111"]', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH('["123", "321", "111"]', 'one', "123"))),
    "nope"
);

$ mysql -V
mysql Ver 8.0.20-11 for Linux on x86_64 (Percona Server (GPL), Release 11, Revision 5b5a5d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IF()` function returns a value if the condition is `TRUE` or a different value if the condition is `FALSE`. In your case, the first argument(*condition*) not a boolean expression(such as *1<2* which returns `TRUE`) but a *string*( the path to the given string within a JSON document), then you'll get `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that when I changed a expression to json_contains function:

```
select if(
    JSON_CONTAINS('["123", "321", "111"]', cast('["123"]' AS JSON)),
    JSON_REMOVE('["123", "321", "111"]', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH('["123", "321", "111"]', 'one', "123"))),
    "nope"
);
```

P.S.
I can't find as convert result JSON_SEARCH to bool